# Cannot change height of UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

In the Apple iPhone Clock App, when a user adds a new alarm a modal view pops up. I am trying to create a UI similar to that.

I currently have a UITableViewController as the root view controller of a UINavigationController.

I also have a UIDatePicker added as a subview to the UINavigationController:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:mydatePicker];
```

However, I have about 10+ rows in my UITableview (that of the UITableViewController) and as soon as I added the UIDatePicker I cannot scroll to view all the cells.

I realized that the UITableView size is the same size as it was before I added the UIDatePicker, and therefore I would need to change its size in order to be able to scroll to see all the table cells.

I have tried several things in order to change its size, all to no avail. In the code below I arbitrarily chose 50 for the new height.

First, tried changing the bounds height:

```
CGRect bounds = [self.tableView bounds];
[self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,
                                     bounds.origin.y,
                                     bounds.size.width,
                                     50)];
```

Then tried to change the frame height:

```
CGRect tvframe = [self.tableView frame];
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tvframe.origin.x,
                                    tvframe.origin.y,
                                    tvframe.size.width,
                                    50)];
```

Then after googling some more i tried changing the contentSize height:

```
CGSize thesize = self.tableView.contentSize;
thesize.height = 50;
self.tableView.contentSize = thesize;
```

None of these appeared to have any effect on the size of the UITableView. I still could not scroll to see all the cells.

I later tried some of the same methods as above but on the UINavigationController instead of the UITableView. I didn't have much luck with this either.

As a last resort, I tried to change the size of the UITableView in the Storyboard editor. I could not figure this out either.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController? Using a plain UITableView within a custom UIViewController normally has less quirks to work through.

Comment: Yes, I am using a UITableViewController (I actually have a custom class that is inherits/implements a UITableViewController). I will update post to reflect this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the `UITableViewController` [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it:

> creates an unconfigured UITableView object with the correct dimensions
>   and autoresize mask

And a quote from the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW1) which specifically addresses this behavior:

> **Note:** You should use a `UIViewController` subclass rather than a
>   subclass of `UITableViewController` to manage a table view if the view
>   to be managed is composed of multiple subviews, only one of which is a
>   table view. The default behavior of the `UITableViewController` class is
>   to make the table view fill the screen between the navigation bar and
>   the tab bar (if either are present).

If you don't want the table view controller setting the size of your tableView, then you need to use a `UIViewController` instead.  See the link that I posted above to the Table View Programming Guide for iOS for other things to consider when going this route.

Comment: Apple i hate you sometimes for making such a mess...!

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem as you mentioned.
I was unable to change the height of tableView of UITableViewController. I tried changing frame and centers of self.view and self.tableview. But failed.
Then I solved it by a trick, changing tableview's contentInset.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44.0f, 0); // here you can replace 44.0f with your height
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the UITableView a subview of your main view in order to change its size reliably.

The frame is the correct value to alter once you have made this change.

Comment: I currently have the UITableview within a UITableViewController, is this not sufficient?

By "main view" do you mean the UINavigationController?

Comment: Or perhaps you mean create a new UIViewController as the root view controller of the UINavigationController, and add the UITableView to this? How would this be different than working with a UITableview within a UITableViewController?

Comment: What I meant is add the UITableView as a subview of your ViewController's .view.  I missed that you were using UITableViewController, Inafziger is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is your real Problem . but for change hight of your `UITableView` and will Display all rows in `UITableView` write following code.

```
self.tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
```

please try it.

Comment: I already tried this as I mention in the post. It does not work. My problem lies in the answer given by lnafziger.

Answer (score 0):

Your are taking uitableview controller, in place of that use uiviewcontroller in that add the uitabelview. Now you can the the size of uitableview.